# Why do i get an Error when i Try to load this Haskell-Code with ghci?

Tags: haskell

i'm doing some exercices in Haskell:
I am trying to rewrite the function "delscnds" as an endrecursive function "delscndsER".
You can see my try on that below.

```
delscnds, delscndsER :: [t0] -> [t0]
delscnds    []    = []
delscnds    [x]   = [x]
delscnds (x:y:xs) = x : delscnds xs

delscndsER (x:y:xs) = delscndsER' (x:y:xs) []
                      where
                      delscndsER' (x:y:xs) akk | xs == [x]   = (akk ++ x)
                                               | otherwise   = delscndsER' xs (akk ++ x)
```

The normal "delscnds" works fine, but when i try to load the "delscndsER" with ghci, it promts me an error in my terminal and i don't realy get the problem.
Could you tell me what ghci is complaining about here exactly?
Also can i make this idea work or do i need a different approach?
Any hints are much appreciated!

Here is the ghci-error:

```
• Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t0 ~ [t0]
  Expected type: [[t0]]
    Actual type: [t0]
• In the first argument of ‘delscndsER'’, namely ‘(x : y : xs)’
  In the expression: delscndsER' (x : y : xs) []
  In an equation for ‘delscndsER’:
      delscndsER (x : y : xs)
        = delscndsER' (x : y : xs) []
        where
            delscndsER' (x : y : xs) akk
              | xs == [x] = (akk ++ x)
              | otherwise = delscndsER' xs (akk ++ x)
• Relevant bindings include
    xs :: [t0] (bound at Übungsaufgaben5.hs:31:17)
    y :: t0 (bound at Übungsaufgaben5.hs:31:15)
    x :: t0 (bound at Übungsaufgaben5.hs:31:13)
    delscndsER :: [t0] -> [t0] (bound at Übungsaufgaben5.hs:31:1)

    delscndsER (x:y:xs) = delscndsER' (x:y:xs) []
                                       ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Exactly what do you want to check with `xs == [x]`? It is not entirely clear what you try to accomplish.

Comment: The hole point of the function is to delete every second element of a given list. (Think i forgot to metion that, sorry)
My idea was to check, if the list-tail xs consists only of one element, because then there would be no second element to delete anymore and the function terminates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
delscndsER (x:y:xs) = delscndsER' (x:y:xs) []
                  where
                  delscndsER' []       akk = akk
                  delscndsER' [x]      akk = akk ++ [x]
                  delscndsER' (x:y:xs) akk = delscndsER' xs (akk ++ [x])
```

As Willem pointed out `xs == [x]` is not the proper way to check if a list contains a single element. Also this leaves out the case where `xs == []`.

Lastly, the type signature for concat is `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` which means that `akk ++ x` should be `akk ++ [x]`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and for pointing out the type signature, as a beginner that helps me a great deal in understand where exactly the problem is.
Also thank you Willem for pointing out, that there is a problem with that phrase.

Comment: @bamm No problem! If you're not already aware of it, you can always check functions and their types at [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/).

Comment: Ah thanks for the hint, i only know that you can get funktiontypes in ghci by the command :t <function>.